Does not see the script file pythonnet
I use the pythonnet 3.1.0 library. The py script is located where the executable file of the C# project is located.
    static void Main()
    {
        string pythonLibPath = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so.1";
        
        Runtime.PythonDLL = pythonLibPath;
        
        PythonEngine.Initialize();
        
        CallPythonScript();
    }

    static void CallPythonScript()
    {
        string currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        PythonEngine.PythonPath = currentDir;
        
        using (Py.GIL())
        {
            dynamic pythonScript = Py.Import("main");
            int result = pythonScript.add_numbers(5, 3);
            Console.WriteLine($"{result}");
        }
    }

main.py
def add_numbers(a, b):
    return a + b

As a result, I get an error: Unhandled exception. Python.Runtime.PythonException: No module named 'main'.
Tell me how to fix it
